# How to change grease pencil brush setting with python script

Tags: python, grease-pencil

I wanna change a brush setting in Python. When I do a change manually, I got this line:

```
bpy.data.brushes["Pen"].tool_settings.gpencil_paint.brush.gpencil_settings.active_smooth_factor = 1
```

However, if I use the same code in the script editors I got back an error because Brush has no "tool_setting" attribute

Comment: You have a typo, but since you didn't post your actual code, I can't tell if it is in your question or your code.  The actual spelling is `tool_settings` (ends with 's') but you wrote `tool_setting` (no 's' at the end).  This is why you should paste your actual code and the actual error message text.  But it also could be your problem.  Check the spelling in your code to make sure the 's' is there.

Answer (score 1):

My question was answered and thoroughly explained by Gorgious earlier today under [this entry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279390/is-there-a-way-to-change-grease-pencil-brush-settings-with-python)

remove the "`.tool_settings.gpencil_paint.brush`" from your code, so that you end up with this:

```
bpy.data.brushes["Pen"].gpencil_settings.active_smooth_factor = 1
```