# Is there a way to change Grease Pencil brush settings with Python?

Tags: python, grease-pencil, brushes

I'm trying to change a lot of a brush's properties with the click of one button, like the smoothing, simplify, etc.

A command like `bpy.data.brushes["Ink Pen"].tool_settings.gpencil_paint.brush.gpencil_settings.pen_smooth_factor = 0.5`  should work, but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Brush' object has no attribute 'tool_settings'
```

It seems that every property I want to change on ANY gp brush that has the .tool_settings... in the property name simply does not work, and always returns this error. Pasting the exact lines that show up in the Info window into the console, still gets the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python tooltip and the statement that's printed in the info console are misleading in this case. You should use directly :

`bpy.data.brushes["Ink Pen"].gpencil_settings.pen_smooth_factor = 0.5`

Let's reverse-enginner how to solve this. In the [Python docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/search.html?q=pen_smooth_factor&check_keywords=yes&area=default#l) search for `pen_smooth_factor`.

The first result brings us to [bpy.types.BrushGpencilSettings.pen_smooth_factor](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BrushGpencilSettings.html?highlight=pen_smooth_factor#bpy.types.BrushGpencilSettings.pen_smooth_factor)

If you scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page you'll see in *References* that this is implemented in [bpy.types.Brush.gpencil_settings](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Brush.html#bpy.types.Brush.gpencil_settings).

`bpy.types.Brush` is the type you get with `bpy.data.brushes["Ink Pen"]`.

`print(type(bpy.data.brushes["Ink Pen"]))`

> ... truncated<class 'bpy.types.Brush'>